# Restore a .bak in azure managed Database SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

I have a database in azure bucket (.bak) that comes daily from another system and I want to create a stored procedure to restore a database.

I have seen many guides about the command `BACKUP RESTORE`... but I get the error:

```
Statement 'RESTORE DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

I have no idea how to proceed... how can I restore this backup in a azue db (or also in a vm with SQL server)??

Comment: Do you know what database system the backup comes from?...that'll dictate your options. Azure SQL Database is not the same as SQL Server (similar to MongoDB not being the same as MySQL), and the ability to restore backups between the two are limited (if even possible).

Comment: The only RESTORE command syntax available on the managed instance is "RESTORE DATABASE ... FROM URL". Did you try to use that particular syntax of RESTORE DATABASE command? [Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current&preserve-view=true#syntax-1)

Answer (score 0):

Before you have to download the [DMA Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) and check if that database is compatible with Azure SQL Database.

Run the DMA Tool against the SQL Server on prem.